# Using devise_token_auth library for both webapp and api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, token

I'm using devise_token_auth(https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) for authenticating mobile devices and I also need to use devise for my web app.

The problem is that a user can sign up through devise_token_auth but if the user signs in and tries to call certain function in a controller which contains "`before_action :authenticate_user!`", I get an error saying `Authorized Users Only`.

I wonder if there's a way to use `devise` and `devise_token_auth` together.

code:

```
class RestrictedController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def stuff
    head :ok
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should know that `devise` is no longer managing user's session. This why it is advised to use `devise_token_auth`.

Whenever you specify `before_action :authenticate_user!` on a Controller, all actions(like `RestrictedController#stuff`) would require the user to be signed in. `devise_token_auth` expect to receive in the query header 4 params listed below.

Here is what you need to do:

1. Sign in using the route provided by `devise_token_auth`.
2. If sign in succeeds, you'll receive in the header an `access-token`, a `client`, a `token-type` and a `uid`.
3. Whenever you'd like to run a controller action where user has to be signed in, specify, in the query headers, the `access-token`, the `client`, the `token-type` and the `uid`